# How to insert SQL query with in a table

Tags: sql

I have a table which has QueryID, QueryName QueryValue column. I need to insert SQL query as value to QueryColum. But I am having trouble to insert SQL query value of QueryValue

```
INSERT INTO QueryTable (QueryID,QueryName, QueryValue) 
VALUES (1, 'MyQuery', 'SELECT MachineName ServerName, ServerType platform, 'Store' PropertyDimension, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(100)) SCName FROM cloud A WHERE A.SC_APMD_Environment In(InnerQryResultStr) Or A.SC_APMD_ManaTree In ('Fish','Store','Payments') Or A.SC_APMD_Team In ('ST','OS','Modern','Legacy','core')')
```

But I'm getting a syntax error.

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    MachineName ServerName, ServerType platform, 'Store' PropertyDimension, 
    CAST('' AS VARCHAR(100)) SCName 
FROM 
    cloud A 
WHERE 
    A.SC_APMD_Environment IN (InnerQryResultStr) 
    OR A.SC_APMD_ManaTree IN ('Fish', 'Store', 'Payments') 
    OR A.SC_APMD_Team IN ('ST', 'OS', 'Modern', 'Legacy', 'core')
```

I don't know how to insert the above query within the table

Thanks

Comment: Please always include the exact error in the question and tag the database engine you’re using. You can edit the question and add those and also format the SQL queries as code

Answer (score 1):

You need to add extra quote as escape sequence. 
The correct sql would be .

```
INSERT INTO
  QueryTable(QueryID, QueryName, QueryValue)
values(
    1,
    'MyQuery',
    'SELECT MachineName ServerName, ServerType platform, '' Store '' PropertyDimension, CAST('''' AS VARCHAR(100)) SCName FROM cloud A WHERE A.SC_APMD_Environment In(InnerQryResultStr) Or A.SC_APMD_ManaTree In ('' Fish '','' Store '','' Payments '') Or A.SC_APMD_Team In ('' ST '','' OS '','' Modern '','' Legacy '','' core '')'
  )
```

Comment: @Umapathy, don't forget to upvote/accept (all) answers that helped you.